# linq lambda multiple steps array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list, lambda

I cannot find out if this is possible, and if I want to push lambda too far. I do not like the double regex (the `Class.Column` is not mine). I have this simple select function :

(ColumNames is a List)

```
string reg = "(.*):(.*)";
Class.Column[] Columns = (Class.Column[])this.ColumnNames
    .Select(x =>
        new Class.Column() {
            Param1 = Regex.Match(x, reg).Groups[1].ToString(),
            Param2 = Regex.Match(x, reg).Groups[2].ToString()
        }
    );
```

Is there a way to set the regex output as z, then `param1 = z1.Groups[1].ToString()`?

Comment: why not just `x.Split(':')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can linq multiple Select to perform multiple transformations.
You also have to replace the cast by a ToArray feature

```
        Class.Column[] Columns = this.ColumnNames
            .Select(x=> Regex.Match(x, reg))
            .Select(z =>
            new Class.Column()
            {
                Param1 = z.Groups[1].ToString(),
                Param2 = z.Groups[2].ToString()
            }).ToArray();
```

Comment: I think the `.ToArray()` is necessary. The casting of the result of `.Select(...)` to an array will fail since it is not an array.

Comment: You are right. What I wanted to say is that the correct way of doing this is using the ToArray() feature, not that it would be preferable.